# Accessing the variable of the base class from derived class in Hybrid Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have written a C++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int a;
public:
    void read()
    {

      cin>>a;
    }
};

class B:public A
{
public:
    B()
   {    } 
};

class C:public A
{
public:
     C()
     {}
};

class D:public B,public C
{
public:

   void display()
   {
       cout<<a<<endl;
   }
};

void main()
{
  A a1;B b1;C c1;
  D d1;
  d1.display();
}
```

I get a message saying there is ambiguity. B is inheriting A.. So B class would inherit item 'a' from class A. Also, C class will inherit item 'a' from class A. Now if im trying to inherit both B and C classes in class D, which item 'a' will i be able to access ?? from class B or from class C ?? Is there any way where i can remove the ambiguity .?

Comment: "which item 'a' will i be able to access" - *either*, but not how you're doing it now. Pick one and specify it via `BaseClassName::a`. Somehow, however, I doubt that is what you *really* want. I suspect a virtual-base diamond inheritance is what you seek. (and there, some keywords to hit google with).

Comment: This is sometimes called ["the dreaded diamond"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your ambiguity problem by using one of the following options:

**Be explicit about the base class**

Use `B` as the explicit base class

```
  void display()
  {
     cout<< B::a <<endl;
  }
```

or use `C` as the explicit base class.

```
  void display()
  {
     cout<< C::a <<endl;
  }
```

**Use `virtual` inheritance**

Change `B` and `C` to use `virtual` inheritance.

```
class B: virtual public A
{
   public:
      B() {} 
};

class C: virtual public A
{
   public:
      C() {}
};
```